# Getting error Didn't find class "java.awt.Point" on path: DexPathList in my android app

Tags: java, android

Hey i am creating a android app in java which convert PDF file into doc file this is my function which is doing this conversation

```
 public void convertToWord(String inputPath, String outputPath){
//        Toast.makeText(this, "Converteddddd"+outputPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(() ->{
            try {

                File inputFile = new File(inputPath);
                Log.d("path",inputPath);
                FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/XYZ.pdf");
Log.d("newPath", String.valueOf(fis1));
                    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(fis1);// <---- GEtting error here
                Log.d("Load1","File Loaded");
                    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

                    String text = stripper.getText(pdf);

                    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

                    XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
                    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
                    run.setText(text);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
                doc.write(fos);
                fos.close();
                Log.d("Converted","Converted");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error", "convertToWord: ");
            }
            return null;
        });
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
```

at this time i have given default path
This is my function to open file manager for selection of pdf

```
 public void openFile(View view){
        Intent fileManager = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        fileManager.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        fileManager.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(fileManager,1);
    }
```

On activity result

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(data == null){
            return;
        }
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        String inputPath = getPath(uri);
        String outputPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/output.docx";
        path.setText("input Path "+inputPath + "Output Path" + outputPath);
        convertToWord(inputPath,outputPath);
        }
    }
    public String getPath(Uri uri){
        String filePath = null;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
       try(Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null)) {
           if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
               int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
               filePath = cursor.getString(colIndex);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       if(filePath == null){
           filePath = uri.getPath();
       }
       return  filePath;
    }
```

Permission
`String[] permission = {"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE","android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE","android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};`
this are the dependencies which im using

```
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0'
//    implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:1.06'
    implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.27'
```

Im getting error in PDDocument line
error looks like this
** Didn't find class "java.awt.Point" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.pdftodoc/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex",**

Comment: `java.awt.*` classes are not available on Android, they are J2SE classes. The libraries you are trying to use are not compatible with Andorid.

Comment: Transitive `java.awt` package is not available in Android, consider using something like https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android instead

Comment: So after adding this what should i do any suggestion pls